# What to do with crashes in obfuscated Android code?

Tags: android, debugging, crash

In Google Play Developer Console, I often see crashes which apper to happen in some obfuscated Android library, like the one below. I have no idea how to investigate this issue. Any ideas?

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at aDK.done (SourceFile:15)

  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)

  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)

  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)

  at aDQ.run (SourceFile:2)

  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)

  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)

  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

  at cdu.<init> (SourceFile:58)

  at axF.a (SourceFile:7)

  at aDJ.call (SourceFile:7)

  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: Do you add crashlytics in your app?

Comment: No, will it help with obfuscated code?

Comment: Yes, add Firebase crashlytics in your app, It will show you perfect StackTrace [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android)

Comment: The thing is, that code is not mine. I do not obfuscate my code. So will Firebase Crashlytics deobfuscate the internal Android code for which I obviously do not have any deobfuscation files?

Comment: Yes, Just add the crashlytics in your project. make one use define crash on button click and you can see the crash report in Firebase Console